# Geometry Nodes: Looking for a way to latch a switch node until it is reset

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

[image]

Here is what I am trying to accomplish. The *Integer Switch Node* (label 5) which is controlled by the output of the *Boolean And Node* (label 6) is normally false allowing the next edge iteration to pass to the next loop step. However, when the current vertex finds a coincident edge that it is not attached to, the *Boolean And Node* (label 6) becomes true.  At this point I would like for the *Integer Switch Node* (label 5) to become true and stay that way, locking the Edge Integer at 0 , until reset. One solution that came to mind was a latch, like maybe a Nand Latch. The two *Not And Boolean Nodes* (label 2 & 3) are what I tried to make the latch with but as you can see that clearly does not work. I was thinking of using the output of (label 4) to control the reset and when the *Boolean And Node* (label 6) goes true the Not Node (label 1) becomes false setting the latch.
I am probably overthinking this whole thing. What I would like to do is keep the next loop steps from searching for an edge after the current vertex finds one and then at the next vertex iteration start looking for edges again by allowing the edge iterations to go back to normal, not be locked at 0. Any ideas would be helpful.